# Inclusion exclusion combinations problem?

Tags: combinatorics

Determine then number of solutions of the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=14$ in the non negative integers $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $x_4$ not exceeding $8$.

This is what I did:

I need to use the inclusion exclusion formula  $S-\sum(A_i)+\sum(A_i\wedge A_j)-\sum(A_i\wedge A_j\wedge A_k)+...+(-1)^m[A_1 \wedge A_2...\wedge A_m]$

my $x$ is $1\le x \le8$ so then my $y$ is $0 \le y \le 7$ shift by one

So then my $S$ is

$S=\dbinom{10+4-1}{4-1}$ using the formula $\dbinom{r+k-1}{k-1}$ r is combination k variety

my $A_1$ is $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$
$x_1 \le 7$

so $A_1=\dbinom {3+4-1}{4-1}$ the same for $A_2,A_3,A_4$

Then by the combination because $A_1 \wedge A_2$ is 0 because 10-14= is not nonnegative

$A_i \wedge A_j$ is 0 then $A_i \wedge A_j \wedge A_k$=0

so then I did

$\dbinom{13}{3}-4\dbinom{6}{3}$

so then I get this answer but is incorrect as my textbook says 455 is the correct number.

Comment: Note that non-negative implies that $x_{i} = 0$ is a valid choice, for $i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. That's probably where you're going wrong.

Comment: I see so that would mean I subtract an extra number $4\dbinom{5}{3}$ instead of the other for my A1 but I still get the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We observe that there cannot be two x's say x(1) and x(3) that are both greater than 8 because the sum of the left hand side would exceed 18 while the right hand side is 14. So we count the number of solutions when there is only one x(k) > 8.There are C(4,1) = 4 choices for this x(k) that is greater than 8. And for each choice we put, say x(1) = 9 + y(1), then y(1) is non-negative and the equation becomes: y(1) + x(2) + x(3) + x(4) = 5. With this equation, there are C(5 + 4 - 1, 4 - 1) = C(8,3) = 56 solutions. So there are C(4,1)*C(8,3) = 4*56 = 224 solutions that not all solutions of the original equation are at most 8. Now return to the original equation, we see that there are a total of C(14 + 4 - 1, 4 - 1) = C(17,3) = 680 solutions. so the number of solutions that non of the x(k)'s exceeding 8 is: 680 - 224 = 456 solutions.